# elasticsearch Full Text Search all fields with start and end time

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

I have the following query that runs, but does not return the correct results. The results returned all do not contain the word requested in the query(none contain the word requested). It may have something to do with the "fields" part of the query, but then shouldn't it return nothing if nothing matches?

```
{
"fields": ["id", "author", "authorId"],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "content": "dog"
            }
        }],
        "filter": [{
            "term": {
                "sourceOriginator": "Twitter"
            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "estimatedDate": {
                    "gte": "2016-07-24T18:14:36.000Z",
                    "lte": "2016-07-25T18:14:38.000Z"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What analyzer are you using for the 'content' field?

Comment: I do not know what an "analyzer" is.

Comment: For a better understanding and use of Elasticsearch I recommend reading the reference documentation or the free online book authored by the Elasticsearch developers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/index.html. Knowing what an `analyzer` is, it's essential for understanding Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use multi_match

```
{
"fields": ["id", "author", "authorId"],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "dog",
                "fields": ["id", "author", "authorId","content"]
            }
        }],
        "filter": [{
            "term": {
                "sourceOriginator": "Twitter"
            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "estimatedDate": {
                    "gte": "2016-07-24T18:14:36.000Z",
                    "lte": "2016-07-25T18:14:38.000Z"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```